# Parser Error In My Code?

Tags: magento-1.9, error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in
>   C:\xampp2\htdocs\magento1.9\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml
>   on line 216

```
<?php // Grid Mode ?>

<?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
<?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>

    <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
    <ul class="products-grid">
    <?php endif ?>

    <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">

    <!--bof free shipping--->
    <?php if ($_product->getAttributeText('new') == "Yes"): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('free-shipping')->toHtml() ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!--eof freeshipping-->
    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(153); ?>" width="153" height="153" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
    </a>
    <h2 class="product-name">
        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a>
    </h2>
    <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Add more detail to question

Comment: it shows the last line end if parser error but i dont know in which part has end if error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at last you can change with below code

```
   <?php // Grid Mode ?>
   <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count(); ?>
     <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
    <ul class="products-grid">
    <?php endif; ?>
     <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last <?php endif; ?>"></li>
     <!--bof free shipping--->
     <?php if ($_product->getAttributeText('new') == "Yes"): ?>
      <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('free-shipping')->toHtml(); ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
     <!--eof freeshipping-->
     <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
     <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(153); ?>" width="153" height="153" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo  $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
   <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
   <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short'); ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Ok, I will do,that but error not solved

Comment: PLease check my updated answer you miss endforeach at last

Comment: Ok, Its Working...Thanx..